# Button array in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Something weird happens when I add a new button to my buttons array.
It wouldn't locate the new button near the other ones but in the middle of the screen.

This is the line in the code where I add the button "Back ti

```
buttons.push(<LogoutButtonComponent onLogout = {this.onLogoutClick}/>)
```

And this is how I add buttons to buttons[] :

```
render(){
    var buttons = [];
    var yearData = [];
     if (this.state.year === (new Date()).getFullYear() ){
  buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year - 1} eventKey={this.state.year - 1} >&larr;{this.state.year - 1}</NavItem>);
      buttons.push(<LogoutButtonComponent onLogout = {this.onLogoutClick}/>)
    }
    else{
      buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year - 1} eventKey={this.state.year - 1} >&larr;{this.state.year - 1}</NavItem>);
      buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year + 1} eventKey={this.state.year + 1} >{this.state.year + 1}&rarr;</NavItem>);
      buttons.push(<LogoutButtonComponent onLogout = {this.onLogoutClick}/>)
    }


    var thisYear = this.state.year;
    this.props.data.forEach(function(dataEntry) {
      var dt = new Date(dataEntry.donationDate);
   //    var dtUTC = new Date(dt.getUTCFullYear(),dt.getUTCMonth(),dt.getUTCDate(),dt.getUTCHours(),dt.getUTCMinutes(),dt.getUTCSeconds());
   if (dt.getUTCFullYear() === thisYear){     
     //dataEntry.donationDate = dtUTC.getMonth().toString()+"/"+dtUTC.getDate().toString()+"/"+dtUTC.getFullYear().toString();
     yearData.push(dataEntry);
   }      
 });


return(
  <div className="WholeScreen">
    <div>
   <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={this.state.year} onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
      {buttons}
    </Nav>
    </div>
    <div>          
      <YearlySummary year={this.state.year} yearData={yearData}/>
    </div>
  </div> 
);
}
}
```

This is what it shows on the website:
[image]

I also tried to put it inside the if{} and else{} statements but this didn't work either..

This is LogoutButtonComponent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class LogOutButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onLogout();
  };

  render() {
    const LogoutButtonStyle = {
     color: 'black',
     background: '#b7e1f7',
     height: 45,
     width: 100,
    }

    return (
    <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} style = {LogoutButtonStyle}>Back to Microsoft Give</button>
  );
 }
}
```

related css:

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
border-radius: 0px;
background-color: white;
border:#7fabd2;
border-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
margin-left: 15px;
font-size: 17px;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active {
  background-color: white;  
  border-radius: 0px;

}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;  
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Probably LogoutButtonComponent just has different CSS properties than NavItem

Comment: Pushing the buttons in an array and show them somewhere else is not wrong, but that's not how we *usually* do **conditionals** in React. You have probably came to React with a `.net` background. Please read this [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) article. It should get you started nice and easy.

Comment: @naortor LogoutButttonComponent does not have a .css file. It probably uses the default one. Is there a way to change it ? If I open a css file to LogoutButttonComponent what should I define inside it?

Comment: @AhmadMaleki Thank you! If I choose to leave it that way, what should I do to handle the situation ?

Comment: @I.zv Please show us your `render` method and ideally your whole `component` code. Your problem is probably with styling which lies within your `render` method

Comment: @AhmadMaleki Thanks I just added it please take a look

Comment: @I.zv Your React code looks ok. You should check the style of `NavItem`. To do so, the best way is to right click on the year buttons in the browser and choose **inspect element** or **inspect**. NavItem is probably a `<div>` or a `<button>` with `class="nav-item"` and has some css like `float`, `align` or something. Give the same css to your `LogoutButtonStyle` and it should work fine.

Comment: @AhmadMaleki thanks. I added to my question the css I found. Note also the <Nav bsStyle="pills".... in the return() of render(). How should I go ahead from here ?

Answer (score 0):

The information is incomplete, but as per what I see and assuming it is reactstrap or react-bootstrap, you may need to use a structure like:

```
<Nav>
    <NavItem/>
    <NavItem/>
    <NavItem/>
    <NavItem/>
</Nav>
```

Where Nav contains only Nav Items

What I would suggest is that you wrap your LogoutButtonComponent in a NavItem component

```
<Nav>
    <NavItem/>
    <NavItem/>
    <NavItem/>
    <NavItem/>
    <NavItem><LogoutButtonComponent/></NavItem>
</Nav>
```

Let me know how it goes !